# auto word count (autowc) and frontmatter clash in my texStudio installation

Tags: tex

I am trying to compile a tex document in the style a journal requires. I can't make `autowc` play nicely with the `frontmatter` command on my desktop installation texstudio (that I just reinstalled).

The online editor Overleaf compiles the following code without a problem. My texstudio editor won't compile it if the word count command `autowc` is included in the `documentclass` section with the commands `\begin{frontmatter}` `\end{frontmatter}` in the document itself.

It uses the class [apsr_submission.cls](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DrEllaSwat/submissionClass/master/apsr_submission.cls), which I have put in the folder containing the tex file with the following code (called `example.tex`).

```
\documentclass[bibtex,autowc]{apsr_submission}
\title{Submission Template}
\begin{document}
%%% DO NOT REMOVE THESE LINES. For automatic word count.
%TC:ignore
\begin{frontmatter}
\begin{abstract}
Your abstract. It should be at least three lines long to accommodate the dropped-cap. Adding extra text. Adding extra text. Adding extra text. Adding extra text. Adding extra text. Adding extra text.
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}
%%% DO NOT REMOVE THIS LINE. For automatic word count.
%TC:endignore
\section{Blank}

\end{document}
```

When this is run on my computer's installation of texStudio (which I just reinstalled), it gives the following error:

> Package catchfile Error: File `example.stdout' not found. \end{frontmatter}

If I comment out the `\begin` and `\end{frontmatter}` sections, texStudio compiles and builds the document, but it's missing a bunch of formatting features. If I remove autowc from document class so that it reads `\documentclass[bibtex]{apsr_submission}`, then it compiles but of course it misses the word count feature.

I have tried compiling in LaTex, pdfLatex, xelatex, and lualatex. They all give the same error. Any ideas for why texStudio is objecting to having `frontmatter` and an auto word count (`autowc`)?